# Winsock bind() failing with WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL for directed broadcast address

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, winsock, c++builder

I am setting up a UDP socket and trying to bind what should be a valid network broadcast address to it (192.168.202.255 : 23456), but `bind` fails with error [10049, `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL). If I use a localhost broadcast address, 127.0.0.255, it succeeds.

[`WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL) says that "The requested address is not valid in its context. This normally results from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for the local computer. This can also result from connect, sendto, WSAConnect, WSAJoinLeaf, or WSASendTo when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0)."  But I *think* this address, 192.168.202.255, should be a valid broadcast address because of the following entry when running `ipconfig`:

[image: ipconfig indicates local IP is 192.168.202.213]

What might be the problem?

### Code

I am new to Winsock programming and am probably making an elementary error, but I can't find it.  The code I have so far is:

```
m_ulAddress = ParseIPAddress(strAddress);
// Winsock 2.2 is supported in XP
const WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSADATA oWSAData;
const int iError = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &oWSAData);
if (iError != 0) {
    PrintLine(L"Error starting the network connection: WSAStartup error " + IntToStr(iError));
} else if (LOBYTE(oWSAData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(oWSAData.wVersion) != 2) {
    PrintLine(L"Error finding version 2.2 of Winsock; got version " + IntToStr(LOBYTE(oWSAData.wVersion)) + L"." + IntToStr(HIBYTE(oWSAData.wVersion)));
} else {
    m_oSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM /*UDP*/, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (m_oSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        PrintLine(L"Error creating the network socket");
    } else {
        // Socket needs to be able to send broadcast messages
        int iBroadcast = true; // docs say int sized, but boolean values
        if (setsockopt(m_oSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (const char*)&iBroadcast, sizeof(iBroadcast)) != 0) {
            PrintLine(L"Error setting socket to allow broadcast addresses; error " + IntToStr(WSAGetLastError()));
        } else {
            m_oServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
            m_oServer.sin_port = m_iPort;
            m_oServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = m_ulAddress;

            // !!! This is the failing call
            if (bind(m_oSocket, (sockaddr*)&m_oServer, sizeof(m_oServer)) == -1) {
                PrintLine(L"Error binding address " + String(strAddress.c_str()) + L":" + IntToStr(m_iPort) + L" to socket; error " + IntToStr(WSAGetLastError()));
            } else {
                m_bInitialisedOk = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Comments

`ParseIPAddress` is a wrapper around `inet_addr`; inspecting the value of `m_oServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr` it appears to be correct.  `m_oSocket` is a `SOCKET`.  I added the call to `setsockopt` since you can't broadcast via anything but TCP by default (see the [second paragraph in `sendto`'s Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)); this call doesn't make any difference.  `PrintLine` is a wrapper to the console output.  The odd `String / c_str()` casts are converting to and from C++ wstrings to VCL Unicode strings, since I am using C++ Builder and its VCL libraries. The IP address is a narrow (char) string.

The [`sendto` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that "If a socket is opened, a setsockopt call is made, and then a sendto call is made, Windows Sockets performs an implicit bind function call." This implies that `bind` is not needed at all.  If I omit the call, then calling `sendto` like so:

```
const int iLengthBytes = strMessage.length() * sizeof(char); // Narrow string
    const int iSentBytes = sendto(m_oSocket, strMessage.c_str(), iLengthBytes, 0, (sockaddr*)&m_oServer, sizeof(m_oServer));
    if (iSentBytes != iLengthBytes) {
        PrintLine(L"Error sending network message; error: " + IntToStr(WSAGetLastError()));
```

fails with error 10047, [`WSAEAFNOSUPPORT`, "Address family not supported by protocol family."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEAFNOSUPPORT)

The output of `netsh winsock show catalog` [(mentioned at the bottom of `socket`'s Remarks)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is lengthy but does include several entries mentioning UDP and IPv4.

A possible complication is that this is running in a VMWare Fusion host; Fusion does have an odd setup for networks.  I also have a Cisco VPN configured running back to my office. Connecting and disconnecting this makes no difference.

One thing that seems dodgy to me is hard-casting the `SOCKET` m_oSocket to `sockaddr`, but this seems to be normal practice for Winsock programming when I've been reading examples. Reading up it may be required since the underlying interpretation depends on the protocol family. It seems a potential source of error, but I'm not sure how to avoid it.

Any ideas?  I am stumped :)

### Setup

- Windows 7 Pro running on VMWare Fusion 4.1.3
- The program is compiled as 32-bit with [Embarcadero C++ Builder 2010](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder).
- The program is a console program only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much confusion here. I'll address it point by point for your edification, but if you just want working code, skip to the end.

> `// Winsock 2.2 is supported in XP`

Actually, [Winsock 2.2 goes back to NT 4 SP4](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intro.html#versions), which [dates it to 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_4.0#Service_Packs). Because of that, I wouldn't bother checking `oWSAData.wVersion` in the error case. There's basically no chance this is going to happen any more.

If broad portability is your goal, I'd target Winsock 1.1, which is [all you need](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html#targetapi) for the code you show, and will let the code build and run on anything that supports Winsock, even back to Windows 3.x.

> `m_oSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM /*UDP*/, IPPROTO_UDP);`

Bad style. You should use `PF_INET` here instead of `AF_INET`. They have the same value, but you're not specifying an address family (`AF`) here, you're specifying a protocol family (`PF`). Also, the third parameter can safely be zero, because it's implied by the first two parameters. Again, it's just a style fix, not a functional fix.

> `int iBroadcast = true; // docs say int sized, but boolean values`

Yup. Don't second-guess the docs and use `bool` here. Remember, Winsock is based on BSD sockets, and that goes back to the days before C++ existed.

> `m_oServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = m_ulAddress;`

You really shouldn't be digging into the internals of the `sockaddr_in` structure this way. The sockets API has a shortcut for that, which is shorter and hides some of the internal implementation details. It is:

> `m_oServer.sin_addr.s_addr = m_ulAddress;`

Moving on...

> `if (bind(m_oSocket, ...`

Although Remy is right that the `bind()` call isn't correct, you actually don't need it at all. You can depend on your system's routing layer to send the packet out the right interface. You don't need to "help" it with a `bind()` call.

> you can't broadcast via anything but TCP by default (see the second paragraph in sendto's Remarks);

You've misunderstood what MSDN is telling you. When you see the term "TCP/IP", it often (but not always!) includes UDP. They're using it in that generic sense here.

The MSDN bit you point to talks about TCP/IP because Winsock was created in a world when TCP/IP had not yet won the network protocol wars. They're trying to restrict the discussion to TCP/IP (UDP, really) so you don't get the idea that what they're saying applies to other network transports supported by Winsock stacks in the early days: NetBIOS, IPX, DECNet...

In fact, you can *only* broadcast (or multicast) using UDP sockets. TCP is point-to-point, only.

> One thing that seems dodgy to me is hard-casting the SOCKET m_oSocket to sockaddr,

That's also part of the multiple network transport support in sockets. In addition to `sockaddr_in`, there's `sockaddr_ipx` for IPX, `sockaddr_dn` for DECnet... Winsock is a C API, not a C++ API, so we can't subclass `sockaddr` and pass a reference to the base class, or create function overloads for each of the variations. This trick of casting structures is a typical C way to get a kind of polymorphism.

Here's a working example, which builds with [MinGW](http://mingw.org/), `g++ foo.cpp -o foo.exe -lwsock32`:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsa)) {
        cerr << "Failed to init Winsock!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get datagram socket to send message on
    SOCKET sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd < 0) {
        cerr << "socket() failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Enable broadcasts on the socket
    int bAllow = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&bAllow,
            sizeof(bAllow)) < 0) {
        cerr << "setsockopt() failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sd);
        return 1;
    }

    // Broadcast the request
    string msg = "Hello, world!";
    const int kMsgLen = msg.length();
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    const uint16_t kPort = 54321;
    sin.sin_port = htons(kPort);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (argc == 1) {
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
    }
    else if ((sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1])) == INADDR_NONE) {
        cerr << "Couldn't parse IP '" << argv[1] << "'!" << endl;
    }
    int nBytes = sendto(sd, msg.c_str(), kMsgLen, 0,
             (sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    closesocket(sd);

    // How well did that work out, then?
    if (nBytes < 0) {
        cerr << "sendto() IP " << inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr) <<
                " failed" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (nBytes < kMsgLen) {
        cerr << "WARNING: Short send, " << nBytes << " bytes!  "
                "(Expected " << kMsgLen << ')' << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Sent " << kMsgLen << "-byte msg to " <<
                inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr) << ':' << kPort << '.' << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It sends to 255.255.255.255 (`INADDR_BROADCAST`) by default, but if you pass a directed broadcast IP (such as your 192.168.202.255 value) as the first parameter, it will use that instead.

Comment: Thanks Warren - that was a very useful answer! I'm not surprised about confusion - this is my first time using Winsock - though I thought I was doing okay reading MSDN :/  I changed as per your suggestions, removed `bind`, and added `htons(port)` (I forgot the network byte order for the port number before!) and now it all works beautifully.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The comment about WS2.2 was just that this program needs to run on XP as a minimum; I didn't want to hardcode a version number with no note. I think it's even available for Win95 with some add ons!

Answer (score 5):

You should not `bind()` to a broadcast IP address.  You need to `bind()` to an individual network adapter IP instead.  If you want to send out a broadcast message, you `bind()` to the adapter that is going to send the broadcast, and then `sendto()` the broadcast IP.  If you want to receive a broadcast message, you `bind()` to the specific adapter whose IP matches the broadcast IP being sent to.